# Modify AndroidManifest.xml of a dependency during gradle build

Tags: gradle

I'd like to inspect / modify AndroidManifest.xml of one of the dependencies during grade build. To do that I'm trying to create a task, that will run after dependencies are resolved / downloaded.

I'm experimenting with a clean Android project created in Android studio. My `build.gradle` in the app looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 33
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.4.0'
}
```

my task looks like:

```
tasks.register('inspectDependencies') {
    doLast {
        println ">>>> config artifacts: " + config.getResolvedConfiguration()
        config.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts { artifact ->
            {
                print "a: " + artifact
            }
        }
    }
}

assemble.finalizedBy inspectDependencies
```

I can see my task being executed during the build, however instead of fetching and resolving dependencies it fails with:

```
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts() is applicable for argument types: (build_ez5uxhpcf4o2sj29hk9b4a0xc$_run_closure3$_closure14$_closure15$_closure16) values: [build_ez5uxhpcf4o2sj29hk9b4a0xc$_run_closure3$_closure14$_closure15$_closure16@95cd493]
  Possible solutions: getResolvedArtifacts()
```

I don't really see that it resolves to ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver. I found similar code on https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-list-all-dependencies-jar-aar-filepath-on-local-machine/43755 , however it doesn't work for me either